# Exclude goals in maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have done some integration tests using Selenium, so I have defined a goal on pre-integration-test phase so I:

- Start a Jetty
- Deploy the app
- Perform tests
- Stop the Jetty

This runs fine in my local server.

However, now I am deploying the app to a dev server with tomcat, and I want this tests to be executed with this tomcat, not with Jetty, and my build fails trying to start Jetty on the same port as tomcat (8080). I am executing a mvn package.

Is there any parameter in maven I can use to skip this goal from being executed?

This is the snippet I am using to start the server before the integration tests:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your problems with maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Create a profile for Jetty container and a separate profile for Tomcat

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Maven 2.0.10, one or more profiles can be deactivated using the command line by prefixing their identifier with either the character '!' or '-' as shown below:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2
```

This can be used to deactivate profiles marked as activeByDefault or profiles that would otherwise be activated through their activation config.

[Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Deactivating_a_profile) is more info